# Non singularity of a generalised Vandermonde matrix through Hadamard product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cv.complex-variables, hadamard-product

I'm currently trying to prove the following.
Consider $k_1,\dots,k_N$ complex numbers not lying on the real and imaginary axes. Then consider 
\begin{equation}
W_N(x)= \text{Wronskian}\big(\cosh(k_1x),\sinh(k_1^*x),\dots,\cosh(k_Nx),\sinh(k_N^*x)\big)
\end{equation}
where the derivatives are taken w.r.t. $x$ and $k^*$ is the complex conjugated of $k$.

I'd like to prove that $W_N(x)$ is everywhere not zero for every $N\geq1$.

If, for brevity, we call $\psi_i(x)= \cosh(k_ix)$ and $\phi_i(x)= \sinh(k_ix)$ then $W_N(x)$ can be seen as
\begin{equation}
W_N(x)= \det \left( V_N \circ A_N  \right)
\end{equation} the determinant of a Hadamard product of two matrices $V_N$ and $A_N$, where 
\begin{equation}
V_N = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &  \dots & \dots & 1 & 1\\
k_1& k^*_1 & \dots & \dots & k_N & k^*_N\\
\vdots & \vdots &  &  & \vdots & \vdots  \\
\vdots & \vdots &  &  & \vdots & \vdots  \\
k_1^{2N-2} & k_1^{*^{2N-2}}  & \dots & \dots & k_N^{2N-2} & k_N^{*^{2N-2}}\\
k_1^{2N-1} & k_1^{*^{2N-1}} & \dots & \dots & k_N^{2N-1} & k_N^{*^{2N-1}}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
is a Vandermonde matrix, and
\begin{equation}
A_N = \begin{pmatrix}
\psi_1 & \phi_1^* &  \dots & \dots & \psi_N & \phi_N^*\\
\phi_1 & \psi_1^* & \dots & \dots & \phi_N & \psi_N^*\\
\vdots & \vdots &  &  & \vdots & \vdots  \\
\vdots & \vdots &  &  & \vdots & \vdots  \\
\psi_1 & \phi_1^*  & \dots & \dots & \psi_N & \phi_N^*\\
\phi_1 & \psi_1^* & \dots & \dots & \phi_N & \psi_N^*\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
The statement is easy for $N=1$, but already gets very messy if $N=2$. I have been digging the web in search of matrices structured similarly to the one in case, but so far with no luck.

Thanks for reading and for any valuable comment.